# Jasmine + Chutzpah in vs 2015: keep getting refrence errors in test files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, jasmine, chutzpah

We are testing Typescript for a new project and decided to use `Jasmine` and `Chutzpah` for our unit testing framework, as they both support Typescript and could integrate into Visual Studio easily.

The major issue we are running into is this:

**The test file:**

```
reference path="../Message.ts";

var messagetest1: Message.CommonMessage;


function CreateMessage() {

    messagetest1 = new Message.CommonMessage(Message.vaildtype, this);

};

describe(" CommonMessage", function () {
    //set them both up the same

    beforeAll(CreateMessage);

    //check both for creation
    it("constructor", function () {
        expect(messagetest1).toThrowAnyError();

    });





}
```

Whenever this is run, this is the error that comes up:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Message in file:////message.bunit.js (line 13)
```

We have the basic references in our chutzpah.json file

Not sure how to resolve this, and any help would be awesome.

Comment: Can you please share your chutzpah.json file? And/Or upload a repo that shows your whole setup?